# How to pack multiple library archives (.a) into one archive file?

Tags: linux

How can I turn multiple archive files into one big archive file on Linux (using binutils ar and / or GCC).

I tried doing things like `ar rcs libbig.a libsmall1.a libsmall2.a` and it doesn't work (the resulting `libbig.a` is empty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried this on my machine and the problem seems to be that you need to extract the objects from the archives before adding them to the new archive:

```
ar x libsmall1.a
ar x libsmall2.a
ar rcs libbig.a *.o
```

Simply running ar rcs like you did produced an archive which contained two .a files, but tools (e.g. nm) were unwilling to look deeper into these files.

Comment: That's what I was afraid that has to be done, but I thought there might be some clever way to do it with AR, hackish-voodoo or something ;-).